# SSIS execution reports show delay in reports generation and moving to next step

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssms

1. Suppose a job has 2 packages. Package1 has 10 steps and package 2
   has 2. After a job is triggered, and assume that SSIS reports show
   that Step 4 is in progress, while in actual step 8 is also complete.
   Why this delay in reflection in SSIS execution reports ?
2. Now suppose all the 10 steps are actually completed, and after some hours of  actual completion the reports also show all the 10 steps as successful. Ideally after this the Package2 must start executing, but this does not happen for next 5 to 10 hours.

Any suggestion on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1.
The SSIS GUI is not great for displaying live updates as to how your package is progressing with large packages. Sometimes SSIS shows red when successful and green when not, sometimes it shows TBC steps as green when the current step is still white. it's something you will just have to put up with until Microsoft fix it.
The best thing you can do (i have found) to see exactly what step your package is at is to setup a table in your database and update it with step & start/finish times. This way you can monitor your table to see when your steps are actually completing.

2.
This depends entirely on how you are triggering the second package to execute, I'd recommend the last step of the first package would be to execute the next one, as long as there are no other dependencies.

Comment: #1 Thanks
#2 The second package is triggered from job, i.e. Goto Step 2

Comment: and you are certain that the first package has completed before the 5 hour wait before next one begins?